# Should the column space of a matrix contain the $\vec{0}$ to be a column space?

Tags: linear-algebra

One of the rules for a vector space to form subspace, is that, to form a subspace it must contain the $\vec{0}$.

But wouldn't it make sense, for the columns to span the whole subspace, to not contain the $\vec{0}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Column space must contain the zero vector since for any $m \times n$ matrix $A$, we must have $0_m = A0_n \in \operatorname{Col}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are given by $c_1,\cdots,c_n$, note that the zero vector is necessarily contained in their span: consider the linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i c_i$ where $\alpha_i = 0$ for every $i$.

This is in fact true of any nonempty collection of vectors: the zero vector always lies in the span of a collection of vectors, by taking the trivial linear combination.

Moreover, I'm not sure why it would make sense for the columns' span to not contain the zero vector; if you want them to span an entire subspace, every element thereof must be reachable with some linear combination, and that includes the zero vector.

Comment: It's even true for an empty collection of vectors.

Comment: True, I just chose to exclude that because that is a bit less obvious/intuitive (since it feels like it largely appeals to convention/definition more than anything)